# Is there any way to avoid fully-specified class-names in a header without namespace pollution?

Tags: c++, stl

We have a lot of classes not in any namespace, which use std extensively.

e.g.:

```
class MyClass
{
std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> mLookup
...
```

This is tedious but because it's a header I cannot just do `using namespace std;` or I will cause awful pollution.

Neither can I (I think) move this class into a new namespace without then having to update every use of it in the rest of the codebase, which is all starting to get a bit of a serious task.

So I want to check, C++(17) does *not* provide any other solution? I just need to fully-specify things or introduce namespaces?

Comment: compilers at version 17 or later allow the following:  "  #include <iostream>   
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl, std::hex, std::dec;  ".    Below this include, you can use cout, cerr, endl, hex and dec functions in this simpler form (without the std:: prefix),  It also prevents polluting your compile with the many other std:: functions of <iostream>

Comment: Compilers have allowed those statements for a **lot** longer than C++17.

Comment: This is still going to pollute with the things I `use` though, right? `using` in  `something.h` will be carried though to any source/header with `#include something.h`? It's an improvement, I'll agree.

Comment: Since C++11, you can use an alias declaration  within the class definition (e.g. `using mymap = std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>`, and then declaring `mymap mLookup` within `MyClass`.  Outside the class, that type alias can be used like any nested type (e.g. `MyClass::mymap a_map = some_object.mLookup`).

Comment: @peter that might be the answer I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking further the short answer is: NO.

You can employ `using a::b::c` within methods or functions defined in header files and you can of course use namespaces in your .cpp files, but there is no way to do this in a header without polluting the codebase.

The proper way is to move things into namespaces but the question specifically asks for alternatives... seems there aren't really any. A lesson when writing new code to avoid this pitfall in future"

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to change everything if you:

1. Have a collection of classes that you wish to move into a specific namespace
2. Your code is well-organized, and those classes are implemented in their own, distinct, translation units, that are separate from all other classes.

The only thing that needs to be done:

A) In your header files simply move the classes in their own namespace declaration:

```cpp
#ifndef myclass_h
#define myclass_h

namespace app {   // start of namespace declaration
#if 0
}
#endif

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();

// ...

#if 0
{
#endif
}          // End of namespace declaration

#endif
```

This preprocessor trick even eliminates the need to reindent everything, and fool syntax-aware code editors into not adding an extra level of indentation. All references from `MyClass` to other classes that get transplanted into the new namespaces, together, get updated as well (provided that their header files are adjusted the same way).

B) Finally, the same thing gets done in every translation unit.

```cpp
#include "myclass.H"

namespace app {
#if 0
}
#endif

MyClass::MyClass()
{
   /// ...


#if 0
{
#endif
}
```

And now, with just a few minutes of typing you moved a bunch of classes into a new namespace.

P.S. In a couple of years your fingers will automatically type "`std::`" without you even being consciously aware of it, so that'll become a non-issue.

Comment: "Have a collection of classes that you wish to move into a specific namespace" - that's the point, I don't. We have _thousands_ of classes/files. Having to change every file which references something.h is exactly what I want to avoid!

Comment: Then, this is what scripts are for. I also have a library with several thousand files. There were occasions where I had to make wholesale changes. After thinking a bit, I wrote a Perl script that did 99% of the work. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Except every file which is modified has to be reviewed in a PR. Good way to make yourself popular unless you can get review tools to ignore this sort of trivial refactoring(?)

Comment: Huh? In organisation where working makes one unpopular it is perhaps easy to avoid. Just do nothing. If you don't know how then learn from Wally in Dilbert.

Comment: The best way to get a good answer on Stackoverflow is to fully explain the question, and include ***all*** relevant details. Otherwise people will spend time writing up an answer only to discover that something relevant was not mentioned at all, but is a problem. Although I have a few more suggestions I'm afraid that they'll end up in the same boat: "sorry, but because of X, which I'm now mentioning for the first time, this won't work for me". Suffice to say: there is no magic button somewhere in C++ that can be pushed to re-namespace classes automatically. Changing everything is unavoidable.

Comment: @ÖöTiib when you have a large mature codebase and someone says "hey let's modify every single file to make the code easier to read" then no, this won't be popular. It's not really productive.